# ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable petsPrice_cal

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have a function to count no. of pets selected and count per price. I am getting an error.

> ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable petsPrice_cal

Here's my function:

```
window.petCheck = function() {
    if (jQuery("#edit-dropdown-pets").val() > 0) {
      localStorage.petBook = jQuery("#petcheckbox").prop("checked"), petsPrice_cal = m; //petsPrice_cal = jQuery("#edit-dropdown-pets").val() * m;
      var a = parseFloat(i) + parseFloat(petsPrice_cal);
      jQuery("#priceTotal").html(parseFloat(a).toFixed(2));
      var b = jQuery("#priceTotal").html();

    if (isNaN(b) || -1 == b.toString().indexOf(".")) b = b.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
      else {
        var c = b.toString().split(".");
        c[0] = c[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        var b = c.join(".")
      }
      b = b.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","), jQuery("#priceTotal").html(b), l > 0 && (jQuery("#discountData").html("(Includes Discount of " + o + l + ")"), jQuery("#discountData").show())
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `petsPrice_cal` is never declared anywhere in your code. recommend declaring it with `const`, `let`, or `var` in the appropriate place. Perhaps it should be declared where you're referencing it, so you might use `var petsPrice_cal = m;` rather than just `petsPrice_cal = m;`.

```
localStorage.petBook = jQuery("#petcheckbox").prop("checked");
var petsPrice_cal = m;
```

Comment: I have tried to use `var petsPrice_cal = m;` but still getting another error  Syntax Error Unexpected token for `var`
`> localStorage.petBook = jQuery("#petcheckbox").prop("checked"), var petsPrice_cal = m;`

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand-what's the new error?

Comment: it's Syntax Error Unexpected token

Comment: Ah I see. I'll edit my response for clarity, you'll have to declare the variable in a new statement.

Comment: Thanks! I have assumed the same and separating them would fixed the error